# I wanna add a shadow only at the bottom of card view, I tried a lot of solutions but no one give me what I want

Tags: android

I wanna add a shadow only at the bottom of card view, I tried a lot of solutions but no one give me what I want.

`app:cardElevation=""` add shadows around cardview (at top, right, left, and bottom), also I tried to do this `android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"` but it not working.
I need a solution plz.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item_root_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selected_item_tic_iv"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_selected_item_tek"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/tiny_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tiny_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tiny_margin"
    android:elevation="@dimen/small_elevation"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/below_large_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/below_large_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/below_large_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/below_large_margin"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/above_med_corner_radius">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_container_ll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/card_border">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/below_large_margin">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/suitcase_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/suitcase"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/old_offer_layout"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_no_margin"
                        android:background="@drawable/diagonal_line">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/old_offer_tv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:shadowColor="#80000000"
                            android:shadowDy="2"
                            android:shadowRadius="4"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text_size"
                            android:textColor="@color/offer_text_grey_color"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/med_LSE"
                            android:text="60"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="1dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:shadowColor="#80000000"
                            android:shadowDy="2"
                            android:shadowRadius="4"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                            android:textColor="@color/offer_text_grey_color"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/med_LSE"
                            android:text="GB"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/new_offer_tv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:shadowColor="#80000000"
                        android:shadowDy="2"
                        android:shadowRadius="4"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/huge_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/huge_no_LSE"
                        android:text="120"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_no_margin"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:shadowColor="#80000000"
                        android:shadowDy="2"
                        android:shadowRadius="4"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/above_large_text_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/huge_no_LSE"
                        android:text="GB"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/validity_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/suitcase_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/above_med_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/above_small_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/small_LSE"
                    android:text="Valid for "/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/validity_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/above_small_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/small_LSE"
                    android:text="15 days"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/price_currency_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/below_large_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/above_small_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:text="AED "/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/above_large2_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:text="300"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/suitcase_layout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/price_currency_layout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_border_color"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/large_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_tv"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/suitcase_layout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_line"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                android:text="Data"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/local_min_tv"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/suitcase_layout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/data_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tiny_margin"
                android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                android:text="Local"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/intl_tv"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/suitcase_layout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/local_min_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tiny_margin"
                android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                android:text="Intl."/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/data_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_line"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/below_large_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/data_amount_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/pink_text_color"
                    android:text="8 "/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/pink_text_color"
                    android:text="GB per day"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/local_min_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/data_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tiny_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/below_large_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/local_min_amount_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/pink_text_color"
                    android:text="30 "/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/pink_text_color"
                    android:text="min / SMS"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/intl_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/local_min_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tiny_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/below_large_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/intl_min_amount_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/pink_text_color"
                    android:text="20 "/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/below_med_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/pink_text_color"
                    android:text="min / SMS"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/check_list_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/intl_tv"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/suitcase_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/above_large_margin"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/small_LSE"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:text="Check list of "/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/small_LSE"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text_color"
                    android:text="supported countries"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/free_botim_layout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/check_list_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                app:layout_goneMarginLeft="@dimen/below_large_margin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:background="@drawable/botim_layout_background"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/botim"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/tiny_margin"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                    android:text="Including Free BOTIM subscription. "
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tajwal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text_color"
                    android:text="More info"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I tried all solustions here so don't reanswer with old solutions.
[image]

Comment: Please follow [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format the code. Also include the relevant code only, instead of putting the whole file.

Comment: For your question, [this](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/53226305.html) might be helpful.

Comment: the link hasn't helped, thank you

Comment: all i want is like the image in link